# Javascript variables between files

Tags: javascript, variables, window, global

Ok, so I have two files , index.html and functions.js (index.html correctly includes functions.js).

When clicking a button in the webpage, a function gets called in the functions file, which updates elements in the web-page (correctly) and attempts to set two global variables ( woind that by doing`window.var1` and `window.var2` . No errors so far in the web console.

After this function gets called, in the index.html I run a code of JS that attempts to read `window.var1` and `window.var2`, but finds them both to be null.

Why is that ? Could you also please point me to some material regarding as to why this happens, not just the solution ?

*EDIT*
I am using jquery and jquery mobile. 
The event handler that calls the two functions is

```
 $('#map').live('pageshow',function(){
            console.debug('clicked button, calling function');
            position(longitude,latitude); //sets the global vars
            initializeMap();
            console.debug('finished with map calling');
        });
```

and sits inside a document.ready() .

*EDIT 2*
I know am sure that the two functions happen sequentially, I am doing a console.log() at their entry points.

Comment: Are you sure about the "after" ?

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: please include the relevant `index.html` and `functions.js` code in your question

Comment: Are you sure the whole execution of your called function is synchronous ? No ajax involved ?

Comment: why do you read the variables with "window." in front ? it should work without

Comment: Please add some code? May be a JSFiddle...

Comment: Are you declaring your "globals" inside a function, per chance? Define the globals at the top of the file (using `var blah` etc.) and then just set them with `blah = nn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb in the absence of full code...

It could be that you're declaring and setting these variables inside a function. Function scope means that they don't exist outside of any function in which they are *declared*. The solution is to declare them (using the `var` keyword) outside of any function (i.e. at the top of the file), and set them inside the function.

Otherwise, they're not global.

Forgive me if this is completely *not the case*.

```
var myGlobal = 0;

myFunction = function() {
    myGlobal = 42;
}

// myGlobal now is equal to 42
```

Whereas...

```
myFunction = function() {
    var myGlobal = 42;
}

// myGlobal now is null
```

Comment: Yorry for not including full source, too big/complicated to clean it up for this example ! It turns out some other function inside that function was asynchronous and that messed things up..

Comment: @Dio *" It turns out some other function inside that function was asynchronous and that messed things up"* => There is no good reason for you to accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The latitude and longtitude variables are declared in the local scope of the function.(I am assuming the code you are showing is the complete code)

To properly use the global scope, add this above your code:

```
var latitude = 0;
var longtitude = 0;
```

Now your function will work properly.
However keep in mind that global variables are BAD. They can mess up your code in the longer run. I recommend you use the [module](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) design pattern.

Answer (score -2):

So I normally do this for variables I want accessible on the global scope, but not to pollute the actual global area:

```
window.PositionData = window.PositionData || {};
```

This line either instantiates the variable or if it already exists sets it equal to itself, so it isn't overwritten.

```
PositionData.var1;
PositionData.var2;
```

and then set/retrieve the values as such:

```
PositionData.var1 = 1;
PositionData.var2 = PositionData.var1;
```

Comment: How is that not an answer his variables are null because he is incorrectly assigning them...

Comment: and he just edited his question to be much more descriptive, it certainly fit his question before...

Comment: Please explain why this is so BAD of an answer it needs to be down-voted?

Comment: you don't really provide HOW to solve the problem..

Comment: this is not true if you use strict mode. removing `window` will badly fail if you have code like this: `(function() { "use strict"; window.foo = 'bar'; })()`

Comment: I thought my answer basically did include a solution, as it is obvious if you remove the special variable declaration he was using, you have to declare it normally like a global variable, 'var var1' and so the problem would be solved...

Comment: @sdepold - he's not trying to use the global object, only trying to declare globally accessible variables, so I don't think that's relevant

Comment: Is that a better answer? Just trying to help people...would like to know how/if I am wrong so that I can learn...